# REGEX isn't working after upgrade of HANA database from version 1.00.122.19.1534210989 to 2.00.037.01.1557479495

Tags: hana

We recently upgraded our HANA database from version `1.00.122.19.1534210989` to `2.00.037.01.1557479495`. After the upgrade all of my SQLs using regular expressions, such as `LIKE_REGEXPR`, do not work. I am getting the following error message when I run in HANA studio:

> Could not execute 'SELECT stuff ...' in 2 ms 710 µs . SAP DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: search table error: [6968] Evaluator: syntax error in expression string.

I've researched on the interweb, but so far have not identified a solution.

I expect regular expressions to work in HANA 2; they worked just fine in HANA 1.

I would really appreciate some feedback on what the issue is and how to correct it. Thank you!

Comment: please format your question properly, e.g. formatting the code, errors, etc.

Comment: Sure. Can you give me some more help on what the formatting should look like? I'm very new to this forum. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please post one query which is not working. We faced a similar issue and were able to fix it with the code below.

Before:

```
CAST(A.value AS nvarchar) LIKE_REGEXPR '[a-z]|[A-Z]' FLAG 'sx'
```

After:

```
CAST(A.value AS ALPHANUM) LIKE_REGEXPR '[a-z]|[A-Z]' FLAG 'sx'
```